# Cannot get POST variables

Tags: php, html, post

I have a PHP file where I am posting variables to the same page but it is not working.

Here is the snippet of that page.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';
require_once 'protect.php';

//$_SESSION['uid'] = 1;

if(isset($_POST['shout']))
      echo 'Posted';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      echo 'Posted';
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="shout">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Shout!">
</form>
```

Comment: give the button a name.

Comment: $_POST['shout'] must work

Comment: @krishna yeah.. he have gave `name for shout` than `$_POST['shout']` should work..

Comment: not working means what does it says some error or o/p not displayed?

Comment: try proper naming to all your html elements.Its a good practise.

Comment: probably you have some errors in one of the files you included.could you check those two php files.

Comment: i tested your code without require_once. it is working.So as i said you have problem with required files.

Comment: @VishalSantharam no erroe. Doesnt echos POSTED.

Comment: could you provide what connect.php and protect.php has and also other coding in the current php file

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Shout!">
```

Name attribute is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php session_start(); 
require_once 'connect.php';
require_once 'protect.php';

//$_SESSION['uid'] = 1;

if(isset($_POST['button_name']))
    echo 'Posted'; 
?>

<form name="form_name" method="POST" action="">
       <input type="text" name="shout">
       <input type="text" name="name">
       <input name="button_name" type="submit" value="Shout!"> 
</form>
```

Not tested...Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the required files. If it shows "Posted", then PHP couldn't find the required files, or $_POST was changed within these files.

```
<?php session_start(); 
//require_once 'connect.php';
//require_once 'protect.php';

//$_SESSION['uid'] = 1;

if(isset($_POST['shout']))
      echo 'Posted';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      echo 'Posted';
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="shout">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shout!">
</form>
```